# Узнать waveform у медиа-файла

Tags: php, html, css, javascript

Как узнать waveform-данные через PHP?

Есть mp3 файл, нужно через [**`waveformjs`**](http://waveformjs.org/) и php вывести вот это

http://src.unotes.ru/s/p3571gn2vh.png

up

Comment: так вам wafeform нужен в браузере или в php ? waveformjs заточен под soundcloud

Comment: @eicto, в браузере, но для этого мне нужно получить из mp3 файла данные о визуализации для `waveformjs`.

Comment: ещё раз waveformjs заточен под soundcloud, там у них говорится, что они используют свой собственный сервис для получения данных c soundcloud и отсылают этому скрипту съедобные данные. резюме **поищите другой скрипт**, или как минимум покопайтесь на сайте waveformjs на предмет исходников их собственного сервиса.

Comment: Нашел несколько классов на PHP. Но они выдают совсем не то, что хотелось бы. Что еще можете посоветовать?